# How to use unordered_map in Android?

Tags: android, c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

I am trying to use a hash_map, defined in the Android NDK, but I get a "deprecation warning":

```
ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/ext/../backward/backward_warning.h:33:2:
error: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may 
be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface 
with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and 
interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-
deprecated. [-Werror=cpp]
```

And since "unordered_map" is present in gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/ and also in gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/tr1/, I believe that there is a way to use it.

The point is that I cannot find it. Which of the following is the right one (if any):

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map.h>

#include <unordered_map>
```

And then, how to use it? __gnu_cxx::unordered_map is not recognized... and I don't know how to find this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a way by adding C++11 support in my Android project. Pretty easy when we know it, but I took some time to figure it out. Neither STLPort nor Boost were needed. Once C++11 was integrated, I could use "**unordered_map**" as follows:

```
#include <unordered_map>
...
std::unordered_map<int, int> test;
```

I created a new question to explain how to enable C++11 support in Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616254/enable-c11-support-on-android).

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want/need C++11 support, you can use the one from the STLPort using:

```
// Here we are referencing the stlport one:
#include <unordered_map>
...
std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int> test;
```

That's because STLPort defines **unordered_map** inside **tr1** namespace, but the STLPort header is not inside any **/tr1/** folder.